# Modifying factory response in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

The web service I am using returns my data in a format that must be modified before I can put it into my view.

Here is my basic factory:

```
.factory( 'myServices', function ( $http ){
    var myServices = {      
        getInfo: function(){
            var promise = $http(
                { 
                    url: "/deal-details.json",
                    method: "GET"                       
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }
            );  
            // some logic to modify promise???          
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return myServices;
});
```

The question I have is should I be doing any modifications to promise inside of getInfo() before returning promise? The previous developer was modifying the value returned from myServices.getInfo() in the controller but that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Yeah if its modification that is not specific to the view its rendering. Then the place for that is in the service [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22617972/2592994)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the **transformResponse** that **$http** offers to you? Something like

```
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : "/deal-details.json",
    transformResponse : function (response) {
        // your modification here
        return response.data;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It really just depends on what needs to be modified - or if it needs to be modified every time or not. If 100% of the time the data needs to be modified, may as well have it do it within the service.

If, however, different modifications will need to be done depending on which function is calling it - then it should probably be done within the controller.

@przno's answer is good if you need to intercept all `$http` requests. If all promises need to be modified, or validated in some way - then that is a great solution! But it seems like your question was in regard to a particular service.

Comment: My gut told me what everyone is saying... If it is general data modifications that need to hold true whenever the data is used than do it in the service, if it is a one off go ahead in the controller.